# How to turn on the Wi-Fi on android emulator device?

Tags: android, android-wifi

Today, I want to measure the Wi-Fi signal quality. So I download the Wi-Fi Analyzer app, and I install it on the emulator,but it showed that the Wi-Fi has not been turned on. Thus I turn it on, but it still shows errors.

I tried several times but it is still not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Documentation. the Emulator Limitations are:

```
Emulator Limitations

In this release, the limitations of the emulator include:

No support for placing or receiving actual phone calls. You can simulate phone calls (placed and received) through the emulator console, however.
No support for USB connections
No support for camera/video capture (input).
No support for device-attached headphones
No support for determining connected state
No support for determining battery charge level and AC charging state
No support for determining SD card insert/eject
No support for Bluetooth
```

So determining Connected state does not work in Emulator. thats why you have facing the errors.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that Android emulator supports Wi-Fi. See [here](http://kmansoft.wordpress.com/2010/07/27/debugging-wifi-in-the-emulator/) for an alternative solution. Still I don't think you will be able to run Wi-Fi analyzer in the emulator.