# My emulator doesn't connect to the internet

Tags: android, android-emulator

I launched up my emulator and tried opening a website but I doesn't connect so I checked its Wi-Fi options and it was off so I tried turning it on but it doesn't turn on, it just says ERROR and nothing happens.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Emulator - Wifi Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849763/android-emulator-wifi-error)

Comment: what manifest? its not a application bro its the emulator, and Jeremy i read it and nothing, still doesnt connect to the internet

Comment: Some other related topics that may (or may not) help you: [Android: Simulate WiFi in the emulator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563370/android-simulate-wifi-in-the-emulator) and [How to turn on the Wi-Fi on android emulator device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067350/how-to-turn-on-the-wi-fi-on-android-emulator-device).  SO seems to have quite a bit on this topic.  Hopefully they help!

Comment: nop, none of them relate to my thing because i didnt installed or uninstalled anything, i just went home friday (everything working) came back today monday and no internet in emulator :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem with the emulator. Occasionally, it boots up in a weird state.it's just an Android adb issue. It may take a couple of tries, but do the following.

```
Exit the emulator
From the command line execute: adb kill-server
Wait 5 - 10 seconds then execute: adb start-server
```

You should see a message that the adb service is starting. If not, repeat 2-3. In some very rare cases, it's only happened twice all year to me, you'll just need to reboot your machine.

Comment: open CMD if you are using WINDOWS and go-to you plateform tools folder inside the SDK and then run the command

Comment: can you explain in details how to do that? and yes im in Win7

Comment: Open command Prompt and type cd command then your SDK path upto plateform tools. inside the plateform tool you will have ADB there . then excute the command --  adb kill-server. after killing the server you can restart the ADB server again by using -- adb start-server.

Comment: ok ive just started it again, so i will try internet in emulator

Comment: Go C:\Users\Alexandre\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\>cd platform-tools
then execute the following command 

C:\Users\Alexandre\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\>cd platform-tools>adb kill-server

after some time execute the following command 

C:\Users\Alexandre\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\>cd platform-tools>adb start-server

Then start your emulator.....

Comment: done , killed it , and started it again but still doesnt work (and also restarted computer before)

Comment: You can start your AVD in CMD prompt like this

C:\program files\android\android-sdk-windowsC:\Users\Alexandre\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools>emulator -avd -dns-server 8.8.8.8
try this ........

Comment: gives me error: PANi C: Could not open: C:\Users\Alexandre\.android/avd/-dns-sever.ini

Comment: but i dont have the program files\android '-'

Comment: sorry try this...........

first make an emulator and in the bellow command write your emulator name after avd   
C:\Users\Alexandre\AppData\Local\Android\androi‌​d-sdk\tools>emulator -avd emulator_name -dns-server 8.8.8.8
 try this

Comment: but, if i close the emulator and open again straight from the eclipse program the internet doesnt work :/ so i have to keep opening from the cmd then?