# Android emulator, network state and internet access

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-networking

I was trying to test the network state of my emulator using following code and allowing it `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        boolean wified = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        if (wified) {
            textView.setText("Wified");
        } else {
            textView.setText("Not connected to wifi");
        }       
    }
    //..
}
```

When I run it as Android Application I get **Not connected to wifi** TextView message displayed on the emulator but when I use emulator to connect to google.com or yahoo.com, it works just fine.

Could someone help me understand why am I getting **Not connected to wifi** message?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, maybe a silly question: And are you using wifi connection? What does your getNetworkInfo return?

Comment: try to run this on device.

Comment: @ManishL Did you mean AVD? Do we not call AVD the emulator? What am I missing?

Comment: @skip i am talking about Actual Device.

Comment: updated my post. plz check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

In permission section in your Android manifest file.

**Edit:-**
Try this..

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo Info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (Info == null || !Info.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "No connection");
        } else {
            int netType = Info.getType();
            int netSubtype = Info.getSubtype();

            if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Wifi connection");
             wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                 int linkSpeed = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getLinkSpeed();
            //Need to get wifi strength
        } else if (netType == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
          Log.i(TAG, "GPRS/3G connection"); 
           //Need to get differentiate between 3G/GPRS
        } 
    }
```

Ofcourse, check this on real device :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I checked for `getActiveNetworkInfo()` I only got `mobile` for the `getTypeName()` of the network, but when I checked for `getAllNetworkInfo()` it gave me an array of 5 `NetworkInfo` as posted in my answer. When I tested your code it showed `GPRS/3G connection` as it should have, given the `getActiveNetworkInfo()` case mentioned above. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Because the simulator can't simulate wifi, see this answer and the documentation. I think it will always return "Not connected to wifi" if you execute this method in an emulator.

[How to turn on the Wi-Fi on android emulator device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067350/how-to-turn-on-the-wi-fi-on-android-emulator-device)

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html

Comment: What are `isConnected()` and `isConnectedOrConnecting()` methods for if I can't figure out whether network connectivity exists or not? I am not too sure if it should always return `Not connected to wifi`.

Comment: As a side note, In the current documentation, `No support for camera/video capture (input).` is not listed in the Emulator Limitations at http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#limitations as mentioned in the How to turn on the Wi-Fi on android emulator device? post you referred me to.

Comment: The methods isConnected() and isConnectedOrConnecting() works on real devices, so that’s the reason for their existent. Only doesn’t work on the emulator like mentioned in the documentation. I don’t know why you start talking about the camera video thing, never read something about it in your question or post before? I don’t get the point…

Comment: @sandkaston: Just wanted to mention that as that limitation doesn't imply anymore in the current document. Had no other purposes. Which could also be interpreted as some of those limitations might not hold as the time goes by.

Comment: Ah, okay, jep, thats true.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] networkInfos = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
    StringBuffer networkInfo = new StringBuffer();
    for (NetworkInfo nextNetworkInfo : networkInfos) {
        networkInfo.append(nextNetworkInfo.getTypeName() + ", ");
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setText(networkInfo.toString());

}
```

Above code got **mobile, WIFI, mobile_mms, mobile_supl, mobile_hipri,** displayed as `TextView` message on the AVD.