# How to check Wifi is connected, but no Internet access in Android

Tags: android, android-networking

I would like to know why wifi is connected but there is no internet access in Android. How can i check it?
My code is:

```
ConnectivityManager cn=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
 NetworkInfo nf=cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();

 if(nf != null && nf.isConnected() )
         {
            Flag2=false;
            Log.e("network--------", "1--------------");

            if (cn.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting())
            {Log.e("network--------", "11111111111111--------------");
             }
            else
            {Log.e("network--------", "2222222222222--------------");
            }
        }

 else 
         {
            Log.e("network--------", "2--------------");
 }
```

Comment: check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16437075/2345913)

Comment: remove ==true in ur if condition

Comment: @Sam that's nit picking, it will work fine with the `== true`.

Comment: not works for me @CRUSADER

Comment: I agree with you @LoganDam

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
public void checkOnlineState() {
    ConnectivityManager CManager =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo NInfo = CManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (NInfo != null && NInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        if (InetAddress.getByName("www.xy.com").isReachable(timeout))
        {  
         // host reachable  
        }
         else
         {    
         // host not reachable  
         }  
    }
    return;
}
```

dont forget the access

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Hope it will work :)

Comment: I think the only real way to see if the internet is working is to actually try access it, like this answer suggests.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I want to apply this on every second and I don't wanna to lose more internet data of the user anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: I used this with Async method

Comment: @Oil It is giving UnknownHostException - even when the WIFI is connected (with NO INTERNET ACCESS). How to solve the same ?

Comment: @Smit Patel can you explain how you did in Async method?  please post snippet for that.

Comment: Received NetworkOnMainThreadException. So, it will not be helpful for checking internet connection synchronously.

Comment: There is no isReachable() for Kotlin, is there a Kotlin implementation of the same?

Answer (score 3):

Use this  :

```
public static boolean isInternetOn(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        // test for connection
        if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Internet is working");
            // txt_status.setText("Internet is working");
            return true;
        } else {
            // txt_status.setText("Internet Connection Not Present");
            Log.v(TAG, "Internet Connection Not Present");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what you are doing right now,you can use `BroadcastReceiver` for your application to get notified whenever the connectivity changes by registering `<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>` intent.

Have a look at docs: [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)
and [Connectivity Monitoring](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html) for detailed description.

I hope it will be helpful !

Answer (score 1):

```
ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null && info.isAvailable()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
```